# How to achieve AutoComplete functionality in jquerymobile?

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile)

I am creating an mobile application using jquerymobile.Is there any way from which i can provide suggestions to the user while entering the data in text field.i.e. to provide AutoComplete functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked this thread in the jQuery forum: [jQuery mobile autocomplete thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-widget-with-jquery-mobile)

It should give you some help in the matter.

Comment: NP, Feel free to click the answered thing if it works for you =)