# Scrollbar in Autocomplete textbox using jQuery?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have used autocomplete in **jQuery** from this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/maxheight.html).

In the normal browser I am getting the scrollbar, But in my PhoneGap app I am not getting scrollbar. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give some height to autocomplete suggestion box and add this style to the suggestion box.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: where i have put this code ?i added in ui-auto complete its not working

Answer (score 0):

The demo you mentioned is for jQuery UI which won't work as expected cos it is in mobile, and you need to use the autocomplete made for mobile browsers.

Refer this post:

[Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile)

Or these articles:

http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-widget-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: am using normal js,i didnt use jquery mobile js