# Android auto complete only after space?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, autocomplete

I have an application built in Html5 and wrapped in PhoneGap for Android

I have an auto-complete input

On a computer auto-complete input **works great**!

In SmartPhone, the auto-complete works only after you make **space** on the Input

(If write numbers first - **works**! If letters - **works only after space**)

**Why?**

JS code:

```
//Run in document.ready
function AutoComplete() {
    List = $.map(data.XXX, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.X,
                    value: item.XX
                };

            });
    $("#MyInput").autocomplete({
                source: List,
                link: '#',
                target: $('#MyList'),
                minLength: 1
            });

   }
```

HTML:

The input:

```
 <input id="MyInput" type="text" 
                placeholder="XXX"  />
```

The List:

```
  <ul id="MyList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> </ul>
```

Comment: it probably conflicts with the auto complete in the android keyboard

Comment: You got me then. Maybe try adding it to the <form> tag as well.

Comment: I do not have a tag <from>, and I did not understand what to add to this tag ..

Comment: In Android, auto complete text view has `android:completionThreshold` property to set. Android wouldn' t start auto completion until this threshold reached. I know you are not using Android' s auto complete text view, but your problem must be something related to this fact. I think you should try setting this parameter somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'oninput' event in the input, ran the following function:

```
function RefreshAutoComplete(elm) {
    elm.keyup();
    elm.focus();
}
```

I run the auto complete manually, and it works

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 5):

Try adding autocomplete="off" to the input tag.

Comment: It does not turn off the AutoComplete?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure ,but try after giving

```
     minlength :0
```

and execute the autocomplete on keypress

may be this will give u output.

have a look at these links also

1. [link1](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js)
2. [link2](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile)

Answer (score 2):

I think this link solves your issue showing how to [Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936266/1853864)

This answer allows you to use autocomplete function of jQuery on jQueryMobile solutions.