# Is there a way to use the jquerymobile autocomplete feature with a standard text input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery mobile. I have a text input in a form which I would like to use autocomplete as a prompt for the user. The user should be able to

1. Type whatever they want (e.g. for the list below: honda)
2. Select an autocompleted entry (e.g. for the list below: after typing "Ac" they can click Acura and it'll auto-fill)

I've had a read of the docs at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/ and http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#option-filter but there isn't any obvious way to achieve this.

What I would have liked is something like

```
<input type="text" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Your car brand">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
```

is there a way to do this using just jquerymobile i.e. no third party plugins?

## Edit

The example in jquery at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/#&ui-state=dialog

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search cars...">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
</ul>
```

gives (Abbreviated)

```
<div data-demo-html="true">
    <form class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-c" role="search">
        <div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-c">
            <input placeholder="Search cars..." data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
                <a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div></form>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search cars..." class="ui-listview">
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-first-child ui-screen-hidden">
                    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">Acura</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-first-child ui-screen-hidden">
                    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">Audi</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

As you can see this turns the list into it's own form. Furthermore the text input field does not have a name or id that can be returned to any encapsulating form. The value is therefore not callable upon form submit.

Comment: I don't get it. The examples from jqm do exactly what you want, or what do they do different?

Comment: The user experience is the same - how do you get the listview to operate as a form field though?

Comment: huh? what are you talking about?

Comment: Edited to help understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Autocomplete on usual jQuery Mobile input field. jQuery UI Autocomplete is one of the widgets that does not conflicts with jQuery mobile. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Here is the explanation: [Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile)

Comment: No third party plugins. JQM already has its own autocomplete.

Comment: I"m going to accept this for now because it does work - however as @Omar mentioned - I'm not keen on 3rd party plugins (which standard jquery-ui falls under in this case) as JQM is advancing quite rapidly and 3rd party plugins are more likely to fail with upgrades in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just see the working example: [Listview Autocomplete - Enhanced](http://jsbin.com/UGARopu/2)

Comment: Welcome to SO, as this is not an actual answer, you should be putting it as a comment instead