# Override jQuery UI autocomplete select on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jqueryui autocomplete like so:

```
<input class="recipe_input_display" autocomplete="off">

$( ".recipe_input_display" ).autocomplete({
  source: "{% url 'recipe_items' %}",
  minLength: 2,
           select:function(event,ui) { ....
```

When I type something into the field on a mobile device, it yields a list of autocompleted options

but then when I select my value from the dropdown it is just highlighted and I have to further select 'done' on my keypad or click a second time on my selection.

The jQuery UI examples are all set up so your choice populates the first time you choose it.

I have looked through their API, but I can't understand what would give that functionality and I don't want to sit around guessing and checking.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery Mobile? Also, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile) or [this library](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js)

Comment: I did try jquery mobile, but it messed up almost all of my site