# Samsung Internet default browser javascript autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, samsung-mobile

I have an issue that only seems to happen in Samsung Internet default browser.

I am using the following where #query-mob is the id of a text input used for searching.

```
var places = ["Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "AndSoOn"]
$("#query-mob").autocomplete({
    source: places
});
```

Selecting any of the values from the autocomplete then hitting 'search' should perform a search on the values chosen. This is working perfectly on all browsers I've tried, mobile and desktop, except samsung default browser.

To add, manually typing "Place1" instead of selecting from the autocomplete works fine, but selecting from the autocomplete will perform a blank search. i.e. it seems the chosen value is not being passed through correctly into the text field.

Any ideas? Also, is there a way I can debug this on the device? Finding it hard to see what's failing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile ?

Comment: I have now, but I don't think it's relevant unfortunately. 

I'm generally not having any issues with autocomplete. It's simply one browser that is doing something strange.

The interesting part is that the autcomplete text IS being pulled in into the textbox, but seems to be ignored at the next stage. As if it's showing in the textbox, but not actually there.

Comment: What version of JQuery and Samsung Internet are you using? Could you create a simple test case? (I tried briefly but haven't used JQuery in a while and I'm getting "autocomplete is not a function" - are you using a plugin?)